# Is there any official timeline of when spells were developed in Toril?

Tags: spells, dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, time

In the 2e *Netheril: Empire of Magic* boxed set there are several references to who, and occasionally when, spells were developed such as "Seed of Moander" p.g 23 in the *Encyclopedia Arcane* and "Detect Living" pg. 13 of the same.

Is there an official timeline of when spells were developed and redeveloped in Toril?  Any official content from any edition is okay and published novels can be used as secondary evidence.

Answer (score 5):

The boxed set *Netheril: Empire of Magic* also contains the sourcebook ***The Winds of Netheril***. On pages 26-28, Table 9 **lists the year in which almost any AD&D spell has been introduced in Netheril**. And the table on pages 23-25 lists the original names of the spells.

For example, consider *Polymorph Self*. On page 24, we read that its original name was *Quantoul's selfmorph*. And on page 26, we see that *Quantoul's selfmorph* was introduced in 1838 NY (-2021 DR).

Having said this, it is worth noting that by the time Netherese arcanists introduced these spells, it is likely that the elves might have already had access to some. Quoting from the boxed set *Cormanthyr: Empire of the Elves* (page 124):

> ... the bulk of the races on Toril tapped only the magics granted by their own gods via shamanistic and priestly magics. For many centuries, only the dragons and the elves tapped into the Weave without divine measure.

Finally, we know that the [Nether Scrolls](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Nether_Scrolls), whose discovery by the humans greatly boosted their understanding of magic, were written by the sarrukh circa -30000 DR. However, these scrolls describe fundamental magical theory, so the Netherese arcanists had to develop the spells themselves.